# Is there a way to avoid self-closing tags when using XML Serialization?

Tags: .net, vb.net, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I am working with VB.NET and I am facing a problem with XML serialization. When empty values exists in the object I am serializing, the XML file contains the following tags:

```
<tagName/>
```

instead of:

```
<tagName></tagName>
```

I know that it's the same, but I want the start tag to close appropriately.

Comment: Interestingly, someone has [already complained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415239/xml-serialization-empty-collections-not-self-closing) about the opposite behavior. The only answer indicates that the implementation *doesn't* use self-closing tags, but carries hope that will change in future implementations. Apparently it has, and now you don't like it.

Comment: I don't know of a built-in way to change this behavior. Why do you need to change it, i.e. what's the underlying problem? Maybe it can be solved in a different way...

Answer (score 3):

They are the same and it makes *no* difference. Any parser or reader understands the meaning, so why is this so important to change?

I find the current behavior better as it will result in *smaller* files.

Regardless, there is no way to override this behavior.

Comment: -1 Doesn't work when the parser is hand-rolled and you don't have any say over how they handle empty elements.

Comment: -1 Some third party applications, such as Quickbooks, don't recognize self-closing tags, sometimes it's needed for integration purposes.

Comment: -1 The SQL Server command 'replace value of' doesn't work on self-closing tags and the treatment for this causes performance loss.

Comment: @Lucas - since when does the SQL server "replace" command = an XML parser?

Comment: You just assumed OP's question was only about parsing XML, he asked how to avoid self-closing tags, and you said that there's no difference. There is.

Comment: @Lucas - OP **tagged** the question with `XmlSerializer` and the question is about XML serialization. No assumptions there. You are the one who decided that string replacements apply.

Comment: But it's needed for integration purposes, see David's comment.

Comment: @Lucas - sure. But that has nothing to do with XML serializers either. That an application treats the two as separate things means it doesn't understand XML natively. My answer, in the context of the question is entirely right (I do say "Any parser or reader" - that is, objects that "understand" XML natively).